# Arrays in my class is giving me an error... AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, arrays, compiler-errors, set

I have this code:

```
level = {0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0}

class player:
    def getPlayerLoc(self, level):
        for i in level:
            if level[level.index(i)] == 1:
                print "Player location = " + str(i)


p1 = player()
p1.getPlayerLoc(level)
```

When I run it it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gamy.py", line 13, in <module>
    p1.getPlayerLoc(level)
  File "gamy.py", line 8, in getPlayerLoc
    if level[level.index(i)] == 1:
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'
```

It looks like it's converting my array into a set object. Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Er, that *is* a set object. Did you mean to use a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
level = {0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0}
```

`{}` brackets means `set`,
declare it as a `list`:

```
level = [0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0]
```

e.g.

```
>>> level = {0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0}
>>> level
{0, 1}  # because set only contains unique elements

>>> level = [0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0]
>>> level
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Oh fail, I totally forgot that xD Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do that XD